# Callback to a powershell function of a COM object

Tags: c++, powershell, callback, com

A long time ago i created a COM class which does some things and also provides a callback registration:

```
HRESULT RegisterCallback([in] IUnknown* callbackFunction);
```

The `callbackFunction` can either be of type `IDispatch` or `ICallbackHandler`

```
interface IActionCallbackHandler : IUnknown {
    [id(1)] HRESULT ActionCallback(IActionCallbackData* data);
};
```

`IDispatch` was used to register VBScript sub routines as callback method e.g.:

```
Sub ProgressCallback (data)
     WScript.Echo data.Message
End sub

Set myObj= CreateObject("MyClass.MyClass")
myObj.RegisterCallback GetRef("ProgressCallback")

myObj.DoSomeActions //this method will call ProgressCallback()
```

However, the engineers try to get rid of VBScript and replace everything by powershell. Everything works in powershell except the callback. So there's no progress and nothing they can log.

How can i achieve this callback in powershell? It would be perfect to reference a powershell function the same way as in VBScript. This way, they could use still their logging objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your vbs example:

```
Sub ProgressCallback (data)
     WScript.Echo data.Message
End sub

Set myObj= CreateObject("MyClass.MyClass")
myObj.RegisterCallback GetRef("ProgressCallback")

myObj.DoSomeActions //this method will call ProgressCallback()
```

You should be able to do this in powershell as such:

```
$obj = New-Object -ComObject MyClass.MyClass
$obj.RegisterCallback({param($data) $data.Message})
$obj.DoSomeActions()
```

---

If your goal is to define it as a function (in that you will be re-using it elsewhere), you have to access the `Function` drive to get the scriptblock definition:

```
function ProgressCallback
{
    param($data)

    $data.Message
}
$obj.RegisterCallback($Function:ProgressCallback)
```

Comment: This won't work. There will be no runspace on the thread to execute the scriptblock when the callback occurs.

Comment: @x0n usually the scriptblock gets typecast to whatever it needs to be as a delegate.

Comment: Yes, a delegate to ScriptBlock.Invoke, which expects to find a Runspace in a TLS (thread local storage) slot to actually do the interpretation of the script. Since the callback doesn't occur on a powershell threadpool thread, there won't be a runspace, and you'll get an error stating this quite unambiguously. You might be lucky if there's no marshalling between threads, and you run powershell.exe in STA mode, and the call to DoSomeActions is synchronous.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. The callback method object does not implement the COM interface `IDispatch`. I guess i have to create a custom class in the script which implements the COM interface `IActionCallbackData` :/

Comment: @AcidJunkie you can call the constructor to an IDispatch type without needing the extra interface. Give me a few and I'll circle back